# Trouble in converting an image from database to byte and back to image

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I have a button and a datagridview in my form. I need to get the image from the database and display its value in the datagrid then get the value of the image in the datagrid to copy it to another database.

Specifically, I'm copying the image (blob) from table1 of database1 to table 1 of database2.

Button1_click:

```
Dim img As Image
    Dim bArr As Byte()
Try
            Dim Sql = "Select ID, IMG from sample"
            connectionOnline()
            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConOnline)
            Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            While dr.Read = True
                img = dr(1)
                bArr = imgToByteArray(img)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr(0), bArr)
            End While
            ConOnline.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

Try
            connectionSync()
            Dim a, b As String
            Dim Sql = "INSERT INTO SAMPLE (ID, IMG)values(@a,@b)"

            For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                a = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                Dim img1 As Image = byteArrayToImage(bArr)
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConSync)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", img1)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            Next
            ConSync.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
               MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


Try
            connectionSync()
            Dim Sql = "INSERT INTO B.SAMPLE(ID, IMG) SELECT ID, IMG FROM C.SAMPLE WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 from B.SAMPLE WHERE B.SAMPLE.ID=C.SAMPLE.ID)"
            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConSync)
            With cmd
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("Success", vbInformation, "Save")
            ConSync.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

Try
            connectionOffline()
            Dim Sql = "UPDATE SAMPLE SET IMG=(SELECT C.SAMPLE.NAME FROM C.SAMPLE WHERE C.SAMPLE.ID=B.SAMPLE.ID) WHERE B.SAMPLE.ID=(SELECT C.SAMPLE.ID FROM C.SAMPLE WHERE C.SAMPLE.ID=B.SAMPLE.ID)"
            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConOffline)
            With cmd
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("Success")
            ConOffline.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

> B and C are databases
>   While sample is the table

below are the functions i used to convert the image

```
Public Function imgToByteArray(ByVal img As Image) As Byte()
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
            img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat)
            Return mStream.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function byteArrayToImage(ByVal byteArrayIn As Byte()) As Image
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)
            Return Image.FromStream(mStream)
        End Using
    End Function
```

The result (in the database; IMG) only shows: "**System.Drawing.Bitmap**" instead of the actual image

Answer (score 0):

You are storing only a "Image.ToString".

Try to use a Binary parameter:

```
Dim yourParam As new SqlParameter("@b", System.Data.SqlDbType.Binary)
yourParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
' yourParam.value= yourImage   ' you can't place  a system.drawin.image here
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
yourImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) 
yourParam.value= ms.ToArray() ' similar to your imgToByteArray function .... 

cmd.Parameters.Add(yourParam)
```

Comment: may i know what is your.value=bArr? also, i'm getting a "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'Sytem.Drawing.Image'." error :(

Comment: anyways, i removed the `b = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString()` in my code since i'm  using img in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", img1)` not b

Comment: @MiharuChan more info in answer